# OConcurrentModificationException In Single Thread

Tags: orientdb

We are getting OConcurrentModificationException in Single Threaded Environment even after disabling Local Cache.

ODatabaseDocumentTx conn = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("");
                conn.getLocalCache().setEnable(false);

Issue is not consistent so we not able to proceed, Below is the log Trace for the mentioned Exception.It happens for UPDATE and DELETE Operation.

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException: Cannot DELETE the record #35:214 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are deleting an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v11 your=v10)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doDeleteRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1672) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.deleteRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:773) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commitEntry(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2053) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commit(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:925) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:590) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:149) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:129) ~[orientdb-core.jar:2.1-rc3]

Comment: Could you post your code ? Have you seen the documentation (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Concurrency.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reason exactly in your code:
`conn.getLocalCache().setEnable(false);` never do this )).

Comment: Thanks for Info, Initially I tried without this conn.getLocalCache().setEnable(false); Code, But were getting it repeatedly, So we added this code in order to Avoid it, Can you explain why we should not do it and what could be possible reason for mentioned exception.

Comment: I suppose you have methods which call other methods, but both top-level and low-level methods use a database. As a result, both methods modify the same document but different instances of this document, which caused CME. To prevent this situation, I suggest you do not connect to database instance directly but use connection pool instead. You may read more about advantages of usage of connection pool there  http://andreylomakin.blogspot.com/2016/05/never-use-long-living-database-instances.html .